# Unable to create Xpath for a logout link in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver(Java) to automate my application.I have got stuck at a place where i am unable to create Xpath for a logout link.HTML code for the same is -->

```
<a id="e-modepanel-logout-anchor" class="s-mode-link" onclick="AAA.DSq.ELU(event, 'e-modepanel-logout', 'EPH');;" style="font-weight:bold;" href="#">Logout </a>
```

Please someone tell me an appropriate Xpath for same.Thanks in advance

Comment: Put backtick marks or 4 spaces to make the HTML visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an open mind, use CSS instead.

The xpath to find that element in particular, would be

```
By.xpath("//a[@id='e-modepanel-logout-anchor']")
```

But CSS is so much [simpler, cleaner, and faster](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

```
By.cssSelector("a#e-modepanel-logout-anchor")
```

Comment: Thanks for the Xpath suggetion.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a FireBug extension(which is a Firefox extension) called FirePath that will allow you to click the element visually, upon which the xpath will be displayed...

https://code.google.com/p/firepath/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/

This xpath works for me:

```
//*[@id='e-modepanel-logout-anchor']
```

Comment: Xpath copied from such add ons would make the script hard coded & are ot always feasible.Perticularly in the above case

Comment: i disagree because it depends how you use the addon. It helps to have a tool like that available if you have to spend a few hours looking at source to create xpaths. You can always edit them on the spot to make them more stable. So either way it will still help speed up the process imo.

Comment: The above selector should work.  I would prefer to do `By.id("e-modepanel-logout-anchor")` or `By.cssSelector("#e-modepanel-logout-anchor")` with preference to the first, but XPath will work as well.  (CSS is faster than XPath in general, and easier to read, but that's an opinion)

Comment: I also disagree with using * as the selector. this in itself makes it slower because it tries to find **all** elements with that id.. since we know it's a link, we should use `//a`, not `//*`

Comment: @CODEBLACK-> I think you misunderstood my point.I was rather pointing out that one should not use the XPath given by such ADD ONs directly as it is.Ofcourse the tool like firebug & firePath are useful,but only to track down the required HTML code for the webelement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chromium or google-chrome browser, the built-in inspector has a "Copy XPath" feature.

I'm sure other browsers have plugins for this too, so you don't need to write it by hand.

Comment: Doing so, however, will create unstable XPath selectors.  Your selectors are much better if you write them yourself.

Comment: Xpath copied from such add ons would make the script hard coded & are ot always feasible.Perticularly in the above case

Comment: @MightyBeast1989 "Xpath copied from such add ons would make the script hard coded" why?

Comment: @Chetan->Beacuse once you create your script with such Xpath, it'll not be able to adpot automatically to any change in the location of the element.For example:-once an element found on the top left corner of the page has been relocated to bottom right corner.In such scenario the Xpath copied from such ADD ONs will fail to locate the element.